# Inheriting $\epsilon$-regularity (Szemerédi graph regularity)

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

**Some preliminary definitions.**
Let $G$ be a graph, and let $X,Y\subseteq V(G)$ be sets of vertices in $G$.
Let $$e(X,Y):=\bigl|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:xy\in E(G)\}\bigr|,$$
and define the *edge density between $X$ and $Y$* by
$$d(X,Y):=\frac{e(X,Y)}{|X||Y|}.$$

We call the pair $(X,Y)$ *$\epsilon$-regular* if, for every $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ such that $|A|\ge\epsilon|X|$ and $|B|\ge\epsilon|Y|$, we have $$\bigl|d(A,B)-d(X,Y)\bigr|\le\epsilon.$$

Notice that $\epsilon$-regularity holds trivially with this definition for $\epsilon\ge1$, so we only have to consider $\epsilon<1$.

**Question.** How do I prove that regularity is inherited? More precisely, if $(X,Y)$ is an $\epsilon\eta$-regular pair, then I want to show that $(X',Y')$ is $\epsilon$-regular for all $X'\subseteq X$ and $Y'\subseteq Y$ with $|X'|\ge\eta|X|$ and $|Y'|\ge\eta|Y|$.

**What I’ve tried.** It is easy to prove this when $\eta<1/2$, since we can use $\epsilon\eta$-regularity to show that
$$\bigl|d(X',Y')-d(X,Y)\bigr|\le\epsilon\eta
\quad\text{and}\quad
\bigl|d(X'',Y'')-d(X,Y)\bigr|\le\epsilon\eta;$$
here $X''\subseteq X'$ and $Y''\subseteq Y'$ with $|X''|\ge\epsilon|X'|$ and $|Y''|\ge\epsilon|Y'|$. Also, when $\eta\approx1$, then $X'$ and $Y'$ constitute large portions of $X$ and $Y$, so the densities of $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$ should be similar. We can compute
$$d(X,Y)
=\frac{e(X,Y)}{|X||Y|}
\le\frac{e(X',Y')+(1-\eta)^2|X||Y|}{|X||Y|}
\le d(X',Y')+(1-\eta)^2$$
and
$$d(X',Y')
=\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X'||Y'|}
\le\frac{e(X,Y)}{\eta^2|X||Y|}
=d(X,Y)+\Bigl(\frac{1}{\eta^2}-1\Bigr)d(X,Y),$$
but I'm not sure what to do from here.

How should I approach this problem when $1/2<\eta<1$? Thank you.

Comment: For reference, this is Exercise 2.1.4 on page 55 of Yufei Zhao's forthcoming book *Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics*; a PDF file of the manuscript can be found at https://yufeizhao.com/gtacbook/.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There was an oversight in my textbook. The corrected statement should be:

Let G be a graph and X, Y ⊆ V(G). If (X,Y) is an ϵη-regular pair, then (X', Y') is 2ϵ-regular for all X' ⊆ X with |X'| ≥ η |X| and Y' ⊆ Y with |Y'| ≥ η |Y|.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm posting this answer for completeness, so that I can close the question.) As pointed out by Prof. Zhao in his comment on my original question, the problem was incorrect as originally stated, and should instead have the conclusion that $(X',Y')$ is $2\epsilon$-regular for all $X'\subseteq X$ and $Y'\subseteq Y$ with $|X'|\ge\eta|X|$ and $|Y'|\ge\eta|Y|$. Then, we may argue as before that $|d(X',Y')-d(X,Y)|\le\epsilon\eta$ and $|d(X'',Y'')-d(X,Y)|\le\epsilon\eta$, so that $|d(X'',Y'')-d(X',Y')|\le2\epsilon\eta\le2\epsilon$, as desired.

I also remark that the book has now been published by Cambridge University Press, and the exercise in question is now on page 54.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a counterexample

For simplicity consider the graph is weighted, that is, every edge can be any rational between -1 and 1.

Let $\eta=1/\sqrt2$.the $\eta\times\eta$ part on the left up side is $+\epsilon\eta$, and rest part is $-\epsilon\eta$.

Then let the $\epsilon\eta\times\epsilon\eta$ part of the left up side be $-\epsilon\eta$.